# Run GeoServer behind HTTPS using IIS

Tags: iis, proxy, tomcat

I have GeoServer 2.23.2 running under Tomcat 9.0.78 on Windows Server 2022. http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ and https://localhost:8443/geoserver/ URL's are working properly. But I couldn't find the right settings for https://subdomain.mydomain.com/geoserver/. When I try to access this site, it says "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT"

IIS Settings: In IIS 10, a Wildcard certificate like

> *.mydomain.com

is added to Server certificates. In HTTP Response Header, CORS is enabled with

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

I use IIS Aplication Request Routing and proxy is enabled. In URL Re-Write, Match Url is

```
(geoserver/.*)
```

and Rewrite URL is

```
http://localhost:8080/{R:0}
```

which refers to Tomcat.

Tomcat Server.xml Settings:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443"
           maxParameterCount="1000"
           />
.....

<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           maxThreads="150"
           SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS"
           clientAuth="false"
           maxParameterCount="1000"
           keystoreFile="${catalina.home}/conf/star_mydomain.jks" /* the same certificate in IIS */
           keystorePass="password"
           keystoreType="JKS"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           />
```

tomcat9\webapps\geoserver\WEB-INF\web.xml settings:

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>GEOSERVER_CSRF_WHITELIST</param-name>
        <param-value>mydomain.com,*.mydomain.com,localhost:8080,localhost:8443</param-value>
      </context-param>

****

    <filter>
      <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,HEAD,OPTIONS</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
      </init-param>
    </filter>

****

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

And finally on GeoServer global configuration, when I add proxy base URL as https://subdomain.mydomain.com/geoserver/ and click to save button, URL redirects to https://subdomain.mydomain/geoserver/j_spring_security_check and it says "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT". Therefore, I cannot login to GeoServer.

I'm missing something but can not see.

PS: Server is not connected to the internet yet. After successful deploy, it will connect.